# Installing php5.5 on Ubuntu 16 with apache2

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I need to use an older version of php for my project (I know that it isn't supported). I have tried adding PPA `ppa:ondrej/php` , but it doesn't work - It couldn't find the package. Is there another way?
Simple

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

doesn't work either; it returns `no installation candidate`

Comment: Try to install php5.5 instead of just php5.

Comment: @bc2946088 the same: "E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.5'"

Comment: 5.5 may not be supported on 16.04.  Try 5.6 and take a look at the link ^^ for additional commands and information if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding the repository
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu
you have to update your repositories. 
Please try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.5
```

You can use php5.6 instead..

Comment: This no longer works. 5.5 has been removed from the repo.

Comment: The PHP 5.5 have been removed from ppa:ondrej/php, the lowest version is php5.6. Note that there are differences between php5.5 and php5.6, so you need to test your code. There is a major difference with object serialisation.

Comment: Great (NOT)!  A good reason not to use other people's repos.  Better to build it yourself then you don't need to rely on other people judgements of 'suitability for purpose'!!!  So now what?